# Mailchimp custom built template hide block

Tags: mailchimp

I built an custom  template custom built html -  with all possible variations - to can be used as a starting template for future emails -  i would like to hide some blocks  in one of emails - i tried to use the

mc:hideable

But not working - short can't hide the content what not need it -  the hideable content  has inline editable text and image too.

By curiosity i checked the code source in chrome developer toolbar
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifndwy1xwxqhxxl/Screenshot%202019-01-02%2018.09.07.png?dl=0
 the hide button is there- but for some reason is set tohidden - to not show up -  not sure what need to do to can enable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got cleared for me - writing here if somebody ouccurs same problem to get on faster;

The custom built  template - blocks can be hide only in campaign when you create a new one and do the edits there , not when you directly edit/work on template.